# 24 V DC to 5 V DC converter for Pi 3B

Tags: voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi

I set up an Octopi system for my 3d printer. I would love if the Pi turns on together with the printer.

The printer PSU outputs 24 V DC and has a couple extra terminals. So to save a plug I would love to have those connected.

I don't really want to buy anything, but I have a lot of electronics laying around, so if there's a circuit I could build to achieve my goal, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What voltage does the octopi need and what plug are you hoping to save? Clarity is needed. Have you heard of a voltage regulator?

Comment: The Pi needs 5v 2A, I think the psu will do fine, I was hoping to save a power socket and ofc power from the rpi not running all the time. Yes I know about voltage regulators, but I don't want to order one (there aren't any good hobby electronics stores in my area), even if I could, I'd like to make one myself. I think I'll keep with the awnser Spehro provided tho as to make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having it shut on and off with the printer  may be a bad idea- corrupted file systems and so on will likely haunt you unless you manually do an orderly shutdown every time.

But you could use a DC-DC converter to get 5V from 24V for the Raspberry Pi. There may well not be enough excess capacity in the 3D printer power supply to provide an extra 15W or so.

Depending on the model they draw something like 2A or more at 5V. My two-tentacled Octopi setup has a 2.5A adapter. If you exceed the maximum draw from the 24V supply you may get bad prints, resets or possibly even damage the power supply.

Or you could use a small 24V-coil relay to switch the 5V from your existing adapter (generally safer, provided you do a manual orderly shutdown every time).

As an alternative, you could leave the Rpi powered all the time and remotely control the printer power using a relay module and an appropriate plug-in for Octopi.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a buck converter circuit I quite often use. If you have the parts you can try building it.

Edit: I have a typo in the design. L1 is 47uH, naturally not 47uF.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see other people are not liking the lack of power switch too. I just got into raspberry pi and noticed it. I wrote this schematic to solve my own issue. Too bad the guys on that site don't have a good forum to post this schematic. I would suggest a variance of this schematic below, but add a 5V relay on the USB 2.0/3.0 port 5V pin in place where I have a voltage divider for the pwm fan in the circuit. And use that to control the 24V power supply.
I peeled off my 5V USB from the USB 2.0 connector on the bottom side of the board. In my build, I took my 5V unreg (before the MAX7704) from TP3. The Debug power off is an optional switch I added so I can shut it down if I messed up programming without unplugging it.  [image]